# Can alkyl halides react with guanidine/guanidino groups?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reactivity, nucleophilic-substitution, amines, nucleophilicity

I wonder how the π delocalization of guanidino groups affects the reactivity of the terminal nitrogens with respect to alkyl halides compared to, say, primary amines?

Comment: Doesn't delocalization prevent reactivity with alkyl halides? For instance once amides are formed from acyl halides, why are there no further substitution on the newly introduced NH2 if there are halides nearby?

Comment: Well, yes, they do react. I guess imino position is *activated*, while amine groups deactivated. That clearly shows in guanidine's very high basicity.

Comment: Yes they alkylate, example  https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo0265535

Comment: @Waylander in this paper they use protected guanidines so they are able to deprotonate an acidic N-carbamate hydrogen; I assume that same approach wouldn't work with a naked (basic) guanidine?

Comment: @Mowgli  I don't know, but if you can access this review it may tell you https://www.thieme-connect.com/products/ejournals/abstract/10.1055/s-2006-926325